I'm trying to run a new water lines to an additional dwelling unit my problem is the only way that I see possible is to tap off the irrigation line1st
I installed a couple outside water spigots and lines for my raised bed gardening for my wife to make her happy which in turn made me happy. But I did that a couple years ago. I merely increased from a half inch to a 3/4 in line and I have two different spigot connections both 3/4 inch valves. And for Simplicity I would love to just tap off that existing line as it's only 5 ft away from my now insulated and wired Barn the only thing to make it official Adu is Plumbing. I figure I'll drop down to a half inch as soon as I come into the barn. Planning on having a tankless water heater. How do I France off all the difference lines without losing water flow when the toilets flushing and the sinks on I'm just confused and don't understand the whole manifold aspect of Plumbing please explain like I may third grader. Thank you.

"Adu"? "France"? Please revise to make yourself more clear. Skip the commentary about happiness and stick to the facts.

Much is dependant on pressure. We don't know that, but this is the general idea.   Do not drop to 1/2" right away.
If you have good pressure,(40psi or above) use 3/4" to the barn and into and out of the water heater.
You then have a 3/4" manifolds feeding your hot water lines and cold water lines that are 1/2".  3/4 feeding 1/2 will give less pressure loss than 1/2 feeding 1/2. Having each fixture plumbed back (Home run) to a 3/4 source will give more even pressure.
Pex or CPVC will work well for you.
It would be an improvement if you could change the 1/2"piping to the planting beds to 3/4.
